# How to use xpath to select a div with attrs?

Tags: python, xpath, replace, attributes, odoo

I'm trying to select a div in an `XML` file using `xpath`. But the div has no classes and only has attrs.

I want to select a div in an xml file so I can replace it with another div, I tried using xpath, but can't find the right syntax to write xpath expression correctly.

Example:

```
div attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'recruit')]}"
```

Comment: Example: 
<div attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'recruit')]}">

Comment: Could you add the whole xml file or at least a bit more around this `div`? There are a lot more options with XPath like picking child or parent nodes, which would help here, if those nodes are easier to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with picking attrs attribute of that div.

Like:

```
<xpath expr="//div[@attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'recruit')]}"]" position="replace">
```

Update:

Also you can navigate the div by traversing through the parent child.

Like
If it has a parent div `<div name='temp' >` and inside this div the target div is on `nth position` then it can be access by

```
<xpath expr="//div[@name='temp']/div[n]" position="replace">
```

If you have identifier in the sibling then first pick that node then traverse from child to parent and then to nth child.

Like:

```
<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('big')]//..//div[n]" position="replace">
```

Comment: I tried, it didn't recognize the wanted div and gave me an error @beer44

Comment: Then you can traverse through the parent xml tag and use indexing for accessing this div in child

Comment: @YHussein just share the relative position of this div

Comment: " just share the relative position of this div "
Do you mean code? @beer44

Comment: Yes like if it has a parent div `<div name='temp' >` and inside this div the target `div` is on `nth` position then it can be access by `<xpath expr="//div[@name='temp']/div[n]" position="replace">`

Comment: the parent of the div is a form, with the only identifier is a string. I tried to use the string to locate the form but it throws an error:
"View inheritance may not use attribute 'string' as a selector." @beer44

Comment: @YHussein what about sibling div or the content inside this div?

Comment: Yes, there is a sibling div with a class. But it does not come directly after it. 
it's like this:
div class ="big"
group
div ...... this is the targeted div !
@beer44

Comment: @YHussein then you can pick that and traverse to the parent and then traverse back to the nth child. here n will only count for div not other tags

Comment: expr="//div[@class='oe_title']../div[2]" should this work? I'm not sure of the syntex.@beer44

Comment: @YHussein yes it should work, sometimes get confused with single and double `//` so also try with `//` in xpath. Also if you are using odoo10 or above version than hasclass() is the better to use

Comment: @YHussein you are welcome. I'm glad it solve your problem.